# Ray-Box-Intersection like in the threejs example but with ugly dashed edges

Tags: three.js

I want to make ray box intersections like in the threejs volumetric clouds example.

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl2_volume_cloud.html

I’ve been struggling with an annoying problem for a long time. I made a snippet from my app. Here is the github link:

https://github.com/Spiri0/Threejs-Ray-Box-Intersection

You can move with wasd, rotate with the arrow keys and move faster with space.

As you can see in the screenshot, my problem are the ugly white dashed edges. I just can’t figure out where it’s coming from and what I can do about it.

[image]

I have tried to reduce the app as much as possible in the hope of limiting the phenomenon.

The RayBox intersection can be found in the shader cloudsFS.js in the shader folder in resources. threejs is initialized in threejs-component.js and in the main the composer, renderer and camera are passed to cloud. There’s nothing that would be complicated in any way, but as I said, I just can’t figure out where these ugly lines are coming from. I reduced the shader a lot so that all the volume calculations are gone. With these, the dashed lines would also go up. I suspect there is a missing setting in the composer, because the ray-cube-intersection is very simple. I have the box from the volumetric clouds example

Comment: Have you read the console? There is an issue somewhere with your shaders: `THREE.WebGLProgram: Program Info Log: C:\fakepath(53,12-96): warning X4713: Sample Bias value is limited to the range [-16.00, 15.99], using -16.000000 instead of -100.000000`

Comment: I'm also not experiencing the issue on firefox or chrome, what browser are you using?

Comment: I use chrome and also firefox. Unfortunately I don't see the console on the tablet. But I found something that helps. In the cloudsFS shader in the function sampleWeather I have a threshold
if(weatherMap.r < 0.1) if I set this threshold to 0.5 then it looks fine. However, I also filter away a little more everywhere but ok. I still don't understand why everything suddenly becomes fine from a threshold value of 0.4. What does the warning mean? I have to google it

Comment: I would guess the warning is to do with you using a value out of range, e.g. passing a function expecting something in the range `-16..16` `-100` instead